# Android Studio не может запустить приложение, если для него установлена недефолтная иконка

Tags: android-studio

В нашем приложении есть возможность изменить иконку, которая отображается в лаунчере. Реализовано это через программную простановку флага `enabled` всем тегам `<activity-alias>` для различных иконок:

```
 public static void setIcon(LauncherIcon icon) {
        Context ctx = ApplicationLoader.applicationContext;
        PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
        for (LauncherIcon i : LauncherIcon.values()) {
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(i.getComponentName(ctx), i == icon ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED :
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        }
    }
```

Если изменить иконку, то Android Studio не сможет самостоятельно запустить приложение после сборки и это раздражает. Она может открыть либо дефолтную `Activity`, либо указанную заранее. Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы студия сама распознавала текущую активную иконку и открывала соответствующую ей `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим у вашего приложения package такой: `com.company.calc`, а `<activity-alias>`'ов два: `com.company.MainActivityDefaultIcon` (default) и `com.company.MainActivityPremiumIcon`.

Открываем конфигурацию сборки модуля вашего приложения и указываем `Specified Activity` в `Launch`. Здесь нас интересует `Launch Flags`. Студия по сути добавляет написанный туда текст в команду `am start` для открытия `Activity`. Это позволяет нам "взломать" команду, переопределив аргумент `-n` для указания запускаемой `Activity`. Подставляем в него текущий активный компонент (`<activity-alias>`), полученный из системного дампа (если в дампе ничего не нашлось - значит стоит дефолтная иконка и указываем ее). В итоге получаем вот такую "инъекцию" в команду запуска приложения:

```
-n com.company.calc/$(dumpsys package com.company.calc | grep -A1 "enabledComponents" | grep com.company | grep -o '[^$(printf '\t') ].*' || echo "com.company.MainActivityDefaultIcon")
```

.. и так как студии необходимо указать `Activity` (несмотря на то, что это будет в будущем переопределено нашей инъекцией), ставим любую (например, дефолтную):

```
com.company.MainActivityDefaultIcon
```

Сохраняем и все работает - можно поменять иконку приложения, а студия сама откроет нужное!